# Friend Function "non-lvalue in assignment"

Tags: c++

My program is not compiling and keeps outputing the same error "non-lvalue in assignment." I've tried looking around the internet to why this is happening but I can't seem to find anything. I would really appreciate some input.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Class
{
      public:
              Class()
              {
                    Var=0; 
              }
      private:
              int Var;

      friend void Friend(Class &object);  

};

void Friend(Class &object)
{
     &object.Var=99;
     cout << &object.Var << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Class testobject;
    Friend(testobject);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error?

Answer (score 2):

You won't need the `&` inside the function

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this line `&object.Var=99;` You taking the address of `object` and than accessing `.Var`, this cant work.

Seems you missunderstood references, you dont have to dereference them (unlike pointer).

Change your function to this:

```
void Friend(Class &object)
{
    object.Var=99;
    cout << object.Var << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the function definition to

```
void Friend(Class &object)
{
     object.Var=99;
     cout << object.Var << endl;
}
```

The reason of the error is described in the following quote of the C++ Standard

> if the type of the expression is T, the result has type “pointer to T”
>   and is a **prvalue**

Answer (score 0):

Replace `&object.Var=99;` with `object.Var=99;` and `cout << &object.Var << endl;` with `cout << object.Var << endl;`

When passing an argument, `&` denotes that you receive the variable as a reference.

`void Friend(Class &object)` means you get the reference of `testobject` in `object`.

`&object.Var` implies address of `object.Var`. You cannot assign to that. Hence the error `non-lvalue in assignment`.